# iOS Remote Development

Tags: osx-lion, xcode, development, ios

Can an OS X Lion Server be used to develop remotely? If yes, could more than one person be on it at a time? Thoughts?

I'm trying to find a way for users without Macs to remote in and learn how to do iOS development.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had seen this before I told you to ask this question on SuperUser

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218321/developing-on-mac-vs-using-virtual-machine-on-windows-based-pc

I think what you're asking for may be technically possible but probably violates the Apple TOS.

EDIT: Upon further reflection I think what you're asking about is a remote desktop connection.  If you're asking for a method for remote developers to connect to OS X Lion then I think you're looking for VNC.  And I think VNC is your only option.  But if that's the case I'd rephrase my question to ask "How can I let people connect to my Mac via Remote Desktop Connction?"